# Custom ContextProcessor with ListView - not showing in template

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am back to django after a few years and I have adopted Class Based Views - definitely a fan, BUT for some reason, I cannot get my custom content processor to show its data. I am using mostly Generic Views on my application, and from what I understand they should automatically serve the context to the view.

This is my context processor (context_processors.py)

```
from models import Alert


def context_alerts(request):
    alert_list = {}
    alerts = Alert.objects.filter(to_user=request.user)

    alert_list['alerts'] = alerts
    alert_list['unread_count'] = len([a for a in alerts if a.unread == True])

    # printing to console - this works
    print alert_list

    return alert_list
```

**Note that when I print the dictionary - it shows in my console, so I know it is firing.**

It is setup in my settings as so

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'part_iq.context_processors.context_alerts'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Finally, this is an example view - I have about 20 or so, all standard class based views:

```
class BuyerRfqList(ListView):
    context_object_name = "rfqs"
    template_name = "dashboard/buyer/rfq-list.html"

    def get_queryset(self):

        user = self.request.user
        rfqs = Rfq.objects.filter(from_user=user, hidden=False).order_by("created_at")

        return rfqs
```

I am simply outputting the alerts in the template as so (trying both the name of the dict and the context processor function):

```
{{alert_list.unread_count}}
{{context_alerts.unread_count}}
```

with no luck.

I feel like it is something obvious, but I am too rusty w/ Django and new to ClassBasedViews to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. There is no key called `"count"` in your "alert_list" dictionary. The template is actually translated to `alert_list['count']` (because of #2) which doesn't exist so it just fails silently.
2. Dictionaries in Django templates are accessed as if they're objects.

so `alert_list['alerts']`

is equivalent to

`{{ alert_list.alerts }}`

Now you can just call `count` on the Queryset

`{{ alert_list.alerts.count }}`

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I apologize - i messed up my initial question, I actually do have it as {{alert_list.unread_count}} in my template (edited). The count is intended to be those that are unread (vs all which is in the queryset.) +1 for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything called `alerts_list` in the template. That's just the local name you're using inside the function to hold the dict of variables to pass to the template. The contents of that dict are added directly to the context: so you can access `{{ alerts }}` and `{{ unread_count }}`.